# oracle11g privileges

Tags: oracle11g, privileges

I have 3 users, userA, userB, userC.
Using userC I have to make a query on usuarioB.subject.
The privilege to userC must be assign through userA. 
what must do userB for leaving userA giving privileges to other users?
Later, how can i give privileges to userC via userA?

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean to assign a privilege to C through A?  Are you saying that A will be issuing the actual `GRANT`?  Is A a DBA?

Comment: userA,userB and userC arent dba,  userA must grant userC select privileges but the user that create the table is userB.

Comment: @user1350772 sounds to me like you want [with grant option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF55031)? i.e. when `userB` grants to `userA` have them do it `with grant option`. Then `userB` can regrant that privilege to `userC`

Answer (score 0):

look up the grant command and grant select with permissions to userA

Comment: the problem is that userA must grant select permission to userC, the table creator is userB, userB must grant privileges to userA for grant userC select privileges

Answer (score 0):

*Logged in as UserB or DBA*
grant select on b.table1 to UserA with grant option;

*Logged in as UserA*
grant select on b.table1 to UserC;